# zope server taking too long to respond

Tags: zope

### Problem Statement:

The erp5-zope website takes 4-5 mins to serve a request even though I add more zeo clients. Number of requests per second is around 10.

### High Level Diagram:

```
          .------- zeo client ---.
nginx ---{ ------- zeo client ----} ---> zope server (mysql and zope)
          `-------- zeo client ---'
```

### server h/w

```
nginx -> 4 core (4 GB RAM)
zeo clients -> 2 core (4 GB RAM)
zope server -> 16 core (8 GB RAM)
```

### Observations:

If i try to access the website using a new zeo client which is not in production but pointing to the same zope server backend then i get good response. When i add the same new zeo client to production, the server response is quite good for a while (say 5 mins), but later overall performance degrades again. Now when i try to access the web site directly using the new zeo client, it too becomes slow (so nginx is not the problem). All of the boxes except backend zope server has no much activity (lot of free ram, no much load < 1 and network is not hogged) but in zeo server the load average is > 2 and all processors are more than 50% used. I also see a LOT OF MySQL threads in the zope server.

### About the Web Application:

This is a university websites for students to register for the courses. It does nothing more than some form filling, image uploading and resizing, printing some forms and document conversion (to odt, to doc, to pdt).

### Questions ?

Is the high level architecture wrong ? Or is there anything wrong with the code (caching or something)? How can i improve the overall performance? Will decoupling MySQL Server from Zope backend help?

Comment: How many threads do you have the zeo clients set to use? This should be low. How large of zodb cache size do you have set? This should be high.

The 16 core machine should be used for the zeo clients not for the zeo server(if I'm reading you correctly). Then, with 16 CPUs, I would create 16 clients.

As far as mysql goes, I'm not familiar with how erp5 works and how mysql fits in...

Comment: Also, there is no need for nginx to have 4 cores and 4 GB of RAM for such low load. It doesn't make sense that your zeo server has that much load. Your zeo clients should be taking on a majority of the load. Do you have this setup with relstorage that it uses mysql?

Answer (score 0):

Go with 1 zserver thread per ZEO client for starters and make the cache size high